# PhoneGap application and WCF service on different domains

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, web-services, cross-domain

I am designing an application for Android using PhoneGap, which basically calls a web-service which for now, it will contain a method which returns something (let's say a string) as a return value. Finally, I want the web-service to handle queries which I am going to do against my Windows Azure database.

My choice of a web-service was the Ajax-Enabled WCF Service. Was this the right choice?

I tried a simple application to see how this works. First, I created a new project in Visual Studio and then created an Ajax-Enabled WCF Service. I added just one simple method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetName()
{
    return "Hello world";
}
```

I didn't modify the Web.config, at all.

Then, I opened Eclipse and created a new PhoneGap Android application with just a textbox and a button. Everytime, this button is clicked, the web-service will be called and the return value will be displayed in the textbox by using the following method:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",     
    url: "http://localhost:11634/MobileService.svc/GetName",     
    contentType: "application/json",     
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {     
        $("#textbox").text(result);     
    },             
    error: function (textStatus) {     
        $("#textbox").text(textStatus);
    }     
    });
});
```

When I tried using this method, I get the following error in Firefox: `"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed`. I then tried to change the data type to `jsonp` and added the following line before the AJAX call in order to allow cross domain requests:
 `$.support.cors = true;`. Now in Firefox, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"d":"Hello world"}
```

Can you please guide me, on whether or not I am using the right methods and on how to handle the cross domain issues please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a callback function for the jsonp call. So:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",     
    url: "http://localhost:11634/MobileService.svc/GetName",     
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "handleResponse",
    error: function (textStatus) {     
        $("#textbox").text(textStatus);
    }     
    });
});

function handleResponse(data) {
    $("#textbox").text(data);     
}
```

See this question: ["invalid label" when using JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084044/invalid-label-when-using-jsonp)

As discussed in comments below, you need to set up your MobileService to respond to JSONP calls:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
      <service name="ServiceSite.MobileService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                contract="ServiceSite.MobileService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I am still getting the invalid label error even though I did a jsonpCallback.

Comment: Can you use Firefox or Chrome to go to the localhost url above and then use a debugger (Firebug in Firefox or Developer tools in Chrome) to display what the JSON response looks like? It sounds like that there is something invalid in the JSON being returned.

Comment: If the response is not in the valid format, it is possible your Web.config may need to change for JSONP, or you may need to create a specific Factory for the service. See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882857/wcf-4-jsonp-and-jquery-cause-parsererror

Comment: The problem is that if it is JSONP, it should be coming back as a function call: `handleResponse({"d":"Hi"})` so server side is not handling JSONP correctly. When the ajax receives this it complains. As you're using WCF 4, this article appears to show how to add JSONP on the WCF side as painlessly as possible: http://www.bendewey.com/blog/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery

Comment: Thanks for your help @mccannf. I tried another approach and used a cross-domain wcf service and used json normally